# I'm making a game, can/should I create an "Enemy" class?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a game for my final project in an XNA class I'm taking, it's going to be a FPS. In order to generate enemies, I figured that I could write a class that imports a model and defines the random size and placement of the "Enemy", as well as his movements and actions. I would then call that class from my Game.cs file. However, I'm having some difficulty with this.

My main issue is that I'm not sure where/how to call the Enemy (which is a snowman) in the Game file.

Here's what I have for the Snowmen.cs (enemy) class

```
public class Snowmen : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    private Camera  cam = new Camera();

    Model snowMan;
    Matrix[] snowManMatrix;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        snowMan = Content.Load<Model>( "Models\\snowman" );
        snowManMatrix = new Matrix[ snowMan.Bones.Count ];
        snowMan.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo( snowManMatrix );
    }

    public void DrawSnowMan(Model model, GameTime gameTime) 
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) 
        {
            Matrix world, scale, translation;

            scale = Matrix.CreateScale(0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);
            translation = Matrix.CreateScale(0.0f, 0.7f, -4.0f);

            world = scale * translation;

         foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
         {
            effect.World = snowManMatrix[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * world;

            effect.View = cam.viewMatrix;
            effect.Projection = cam.projectionMatrix;
            effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
         }

           mesh.Draw();
         }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        DrawSnowMan( snowMan, gameTime ); 
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

As of right now, My *Game1.cs* file is a functional skybox and also contains `LoadContent()` and `Draw()` methods. Is the enemy class completely unnecessary?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from Game and not GameObject ?

Comment: How many snowmen does an object of your class represent? 1? Then it should be `Snowman`, singular.

Comment: @asawyer I'm just kind of new to this and didn't realize the difference. If I inherit to GameObject, I get errors stating that 'Content' does not exist in the current context. I also get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Draw'. I see where GameObject makes more sense, but how would I then implement?

Comment: You're right MPelletier, I'll be sure to change that. At some point, I plan on creating an array of them, but the class name should be changed to reflect quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have snowmen than this is fine. When you add other enemies, or similar objects then adding a Parent class such as Enemy is useful both structurally, and it allows you to centralize your code and reduce/eliminate duplicate code.

Comment: Thank you Brent, that's what I was hoping for. I'm going to take Asawyer's and your advice and keep plugging away

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use a DrawableGameObject

```
public class Snowman : DrawableGameObject
{
    private Camera  cam = new Camera();

    //Model snowMan;
    //Matrix[] snowManMatrix;

    public Model snowMan {get;set;};
    public Matrix[] snowManMatrix{get;set;};

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        //snowMan = Content.Load<Model>( "Models\\snowman" );
        snowManMatrix = new Matrix[ snowMan.Bones.Count ];
        snowMan.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo( snowManMatrix );
    }

    public void DrawSnowMan(Model model, GameTime gameTime) 
    {
        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes) 
        {
            Matrix world, scale, translation;

            scale = Matrix.CreateScale(0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);
            translation = Matrix.CreateScale(0.0f, 0.7f, -4.0f);

            world = scale * translation;

         foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
         {
            effect.World = snowManMatrix[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * world;

            effect.View = cam.viewMatrix;
            effect.Projection = cam.projectionMatrix;
            effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
         }

           mesh.Draw();
         }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        DrawSnowMan( snowMan, gameTime ); 
    }
}
```

**In Game1.cs**

Initialize

```
   Snowman snowDude= new Snowman();
   Components.Add(snowDude);
```

And move

```
   //snowDude = Content.Load<Model>( "Models\\snowman" ); 
   snowDude.snowMan = Content.Load<Model>( "Models\\snowman" );
```

into Game1's LoadContent

Adding to Components means that snowDude's Update and Draw are called whenever Game1's is. I am honestly not 100% on in what order though. I believe Load Content should be called as well but I think it is better practice (at least while you're learning) to import all of your sounds/animations/sprites in the same place (in your main file) so that you know exactly what is being called and when.

**OR** 
instead of Components.Add(snowDude);

You can just call snowDude.Draw(gametime) in Game1's Draw Method. and snowDude.Update() in Game1's Update method.

And otherwise I agree with Brent. If there are only Snowmen then you should be fine with only one class but if you start adding more there will be a lot of overlap, so making an Enemy Class

```
public class Enemy: DrawableGameObject{}
```

and changing SnowMan to

```
public class SnowMan:Enemy{}
```

should be appropriate.

Comment: WOW thank you SO MUCH Reafexus! That is definitely what I was looking for! I did run into some errors though, if I declare the Snowman 'snowDude' into Initialize, snowDude .Content.Load... in LoadContent, I get an error saying that 'object does not exist in this context'. Moving the declaration of snowDude to the top of the code just above the constructor will get rid of that error, but bring two more (cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member' and 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model' to 'FINALPROJECT.Snowman'

Comment: I made a few changes. The first is just good practice but I am not 100% will fix the first error but the second should almost definitely fix the 2nd. I misread the code. Instead of snowDude, it should have been snowDude.snowMan in the LoadContent Line. Because snowMan is the model. SnowDude is the actual SnowMan.

The first thing I fixed was added 'public' and getters and setters to your variables which should allow better access to them. When a variable has no 'public' or 'private' it is actually 'default' which is kind of funky to work with especially since you probably want 'public' anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect your game to grow considerably, you might consider an entity system:

http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/

An entity system can help you overcome some of the design challenges inherent in traditional object-oriented solutions (Deep hierarchies, god objects, etc.) as well as keep your game flexible in the face of change.